# How to use Lerp Dash Movement in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm doing a beginner project in Unity and want to use Vector3.Lerp to do animation for the dash movement. Here is my code and I'm struggling to see why it doesn't work.

```
    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.E))
        {
            Vector3 start = transform.position;
            Vector3 dash = new Vector3(start.x + m_DashDist, start.y);
            transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(start, dash, Time.deltaTime);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### How `Lerp` Works

The last argument you pass to the `Lerp` function is a float value (mostly between `0f` and `1f`).

- If this value is `0f`, `Lerp` will return the first argument (let's say `_dashStart`).
- If this value is `1f`, `Lerp` will return the second argument (let's say `_dashEnd`).
- If this value is `0.5f`, `Lerp` will return the "mid" between the first and the second argument.

As you can see, this function interpolates between these two arguments depending on the third argument.

This function has to be called every frame and the float value (the 3rd argument) needs to be incremented by `Time.deltaTime` every frame in your case.

But your if block is only executed once, when you press `E`. For instance, you can set a `bool` to true when the `E` key has been pressed. Here is the further code – hopefully with no mistakes:

```
public float dashTime = 0.1f;

private float _currentDashTime = 0f;
private bool _isDashing = false;
private Vector3 _dashStart, _dashEnd;

void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.E))
    {
        if (_isDashing == false)
        {
            // dash starts
            _isDashing = true;
            _currentDashTime = 0;
            _dashStart = transform.position;
            _dashEnd = new Vector3(_dashStart.x + m_DashDist, _dashStart.y);
        }
    }

    if (_isDashing)
    {
        // incrementing time
        _currentDashTime += Time.deltaTime;

        // a value between 0 and 1
        float perc = Mathf.Clamp01(_currentDashTime / dashTime);

        // updating position
        transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(_dashStart, _dashEnd, perc);

        if (_currentDashTime >= dashTime)
        {
            // dash finished
            _isDashing = false;
            transform.position = _dashEnd;
        }
    }
}
```

There are different ways of using `Lerp`. I mostly use this approach.

Comment: I have tried to follow ur code, but still the object move just a little while i press E. I guess it still frame based :(

Comment: I found a mistake. I'm editing my answer.

Comment: The code executable now, but a new problem arises which is the object keep moving until dashTime (it doesnt stop at dashEnd, and in fact it goes further). I found out that the transform.position keep update by frame., same as the dashStart and dashEnd. Im still find out how to fix this. Please help if u know the way. Thanks

Comment: Omg. I finally saw it out. Thanks, my bad. I still put the dashStart and dashEnd inside the Update(), but not inside the if(). I got it now XD